# What are the Slot Names in a Dataset?

Tags: dataset

I have a dataset which are keyed on `{"Item", "Hour of Day", "Value"}.`

In the examples, I noticed that it is possible to apply functions using such as

```
Select[(#a > 1 &)]
```

But what would the slot name be for my string values above? Is there a way to interrogate a dataset for its slots?

Should I simply avoid the issue and rename them if I wish to perform such operations?

Comment: Did you try `#["Item"]` and `#Item` as described in the [docu](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html)?

Comment: @Karsten7. Thanks, that does it. If you had put this as an answer, then I would be happy to close the question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The functionality of `Slot(#)` got extended in Mma version 10. As described in the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Slot.html) you can use

```
#["Item"]
```

or

```
#Item
```

to pick out the elements with the key "Item".

**Edit:**
As pointed out in the comment by @alancalvitti

```
#"Item"
```

also works, as

```
#"Item" & // InputForm
```

> #Item &

and can be used for your second key:

```
#"Hour of Day"
```

Comment: For keys with protected characters need quotes in the 2nd form above: #"SUBJECT_ID"

Comment: Quoted names are not documented for special characters (spaced cases for example). Nice Tip. +1

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are not strings, then it is a bit trickier, as Slot[keyname] does not seem to work. The only form I have managed to get working is, for example,

```
Select[Key[keyname][#] > 1 &][dataset]
```